# Wronskian for $y_1(x) = x^3$ and $y_2(x) = |x|x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The wronskian for the pair of equations above is zero for all x, and yet the two equations are linearly dependent (where one is a the other one times a constant) just when we consider only x < 0 or x > 0. The Wronskian usually indicates linear independence, but does it fail here due to the fact that the third derivative of $y_2$ is discontinous (even though the function itself and its first two derivatives are), or is there something else I'm missing here (ie some conditions the functions have to satisfy in order to use the Wronskian to check for linear dependence)?

Edit: Correct me if I'm wrong (or let me know if this argument works), but I think the Wronskain is used with solutions to a given differential equation, and since $y_1$ and $y_2$ have the same value and slope at x=0, they must solve different differential equations (assuming the equations are continuous) so we can't use the Wronskian on them like this